# Browser unable to load theme.css.php file from magento skin folder

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, magento, cpanel

I am using cpanel as hosting.
I have used [Gala Electronues Market Responsive Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/gala-electronues-market-responsive-theme/4138219)

I have tested in localhost it's working fine but when I have try to install on live hosting server, one of theme file is not loading.

my live urls is [www.freshdeals.co.in](http://www.freshdeals.co.in)

Can any one have face this problem or can help me to resolved the issue.

Comment: How are you referencing your css file? Please provide relevant code here for future readers.

Comment: @KJ i am new to magento, but if you inspect the site you will get that one of the file is not loading but other files are loading from skin folder.

Comment: why did you name your file theme.css.php ? Should it be themecss.php?

Comment: i have used default quickstart magento installation, they have placed this file in skin folder.

Comment: Yep, @PaulBrunache is right. The actual file name is "theme.css.php" but it looks like there is a URL rewrite that you are supposed to call it without the ".php": http://www.freshdeals.co.in/skin/frontend/default/galaelectronues/css/theme.css

Comment: How i can do that can you give me any ideas. i have tried in .htaccess but not succeed

Comment: I would try redownloading the theme from theme forest and re-installing it

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app\design\frontend\default\galaelectronues\template\page\html`

open `em_head.php`

Remove `.php` from `css/theme.css.php`

and it will look like `href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/theme.css').'?'.http_build_query($setting->getAllCssConfig(), '', '&amp;'); ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the answer to your issue because the same thing I face

Comment the .htaccess file in root directory and remove the cache then the file **theme.css.php** was work properly.

see the below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180730/browser-unable-to-load-theme-css-php-file-from-magento-skin-folder/180732#180732